# Is using a simple ChangeNotifier the proper way to trigger rebuild in a HookWidget without maintaining a state?

Tags: flutter, flutter-hooks

I am implementing setting switch where the value is directly loaded from the shared preference, and when it is changed the value is written into it, and trigger a rebuild to load it again. The setting switch is a `HookWidget` as follow:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';

class SettingSwitch extends HookWidget {
  const SettingSwitch({required this.sharedPrefKey, required this.initial});

  final String sharedPrefKey;
  final bool initial;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final changeNotifier = useListenable(ChangeNotifier());
    return CupertinoSwitch(
      value: SharedPrefs.instance.getBool(sharedPrefKey) ?? initial,
      onChanged: (value) {
        SharedPrefs.instance.setBool(sharedPrefKey, value);
        changeNotifier.notifyListeners();
      }
    );
  }
}
```

where `SharedPrefs` is a class to cache the `SharedPreferences` instance with the `init()` method called at app startup:

```dart
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class SharedPrefs {
  static late final SharedPreferences instance;

  static Future<SharedPreferences> init() async =>
      instance = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
}
```

I am not sure if this is the optimal way to write the widget as I have never seen any code examples with a direct use of a bare `ChangeNotifier` without using it as a mixin or as a base class. Is this the best way to make a `HookWidget` which triggers a rebuild on its own?

Comment: This seems like a pretty backwards way of doing this.  I would either use a Stateful class, because this is a simple bool.  Or I might opt for a useState, the changing of which will rebuild the widget just like this roundabout listener.